# Understanding cats.effect.Concurrent with respect to Cancellation

Tags: scala, cats-effect

Given:

#### build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "2.1.3"
```

#### src/main/scala/net/Main.scala

```
package net

import cats.effect._
import cats.implicits._
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object App extends IOApp { self: IOApp =>
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    for {
      _ <- uncancellable
      _ <- notUncancellable
    } yield ExitCode.Success

  private def uncancellable: IO[Unit] = {
    val tick: IO[Unit] = Concurrent[IO].uncancelable(self.timer.sleep(10.seconds))

    for {
      _ <- IO(println("uncancellable"))
      fiber <- Concurrent[IO].start(tick)
      _ <- IO(println("seconds begin: " + FiniteDuration.apply(System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS).toSeconds))
      _ <- fiber.cancel
      _ <- fiber.join
      _ <- IO(println("seconds done : " + FiniteDuration.apply(System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS).toSeconds))
    } yield ()
  }

  private def notUncancellable: IO[Unit] = {
    val tick: IO[Unit] = self.timer.sleep(10.seconds)

    for {
      _ <- IO(println("notUncancellable"))
      fiber <- Concurrent[IO].start(tick)
      _ <- IO(println("seconds begin: " + FiniteDuration.apply(System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS).toSeconds))
      _ <- fiber.cancel
      _ <- fiber.join
      _ <- IO(println("seconds done : " + FiniteDuration.apply(System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS).toSeconds))
    } yield ()
  }
}
```

Running it shows the following output:

```
sbt:cats-effect-cancellation-question> run
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/cats-effect-cancellation-questions/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/cats-effect-cancellation-questions/target/scala-2.13/cats-effect-cancellation-question_2.13-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running net.App 
uncancellable
seconds begin: 303045
seconds done : 303055
notUncancellable
seconds begin: 303055
^C$
```

Note that, after ~30 seconds, I cancelled it.

Why did `"seconds done :` not print out for:

```
notUncancellable
seconds begin: 303055
^C$
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uncancellable` is self explanatory I believe.

In non-canclellable you have a situation like in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/268#issuecomment-395724552).

As Alexandru Nedelcu says:

> `fiber.cancel` makes `fiber.join` to be non-terminating in the case of IO. Therefore `fiber.join` will never complete and that guarantee never gets a chance to be evaluated.
>
> You can force an evaluation if you cancel that too, which in a real app you'd need to do if you cared for the result of that `fiber.join`.

As far as I can tell this is a possible interpretation of [the contract](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/Fiber.scala#L76)

```
  /**
   * Returns a new task that will await for the completion of the
   * underlying fiber, (asynchronously) blocking the current run-loop
   * until that result is available.
   */
  def join: F[A]
```

Cancelled fiber cannot return successful value - that's obvious. But if it returned exception of another failure... it would also be returned a value, which could be considered value computed by fiber - which should not return any value, because it was cancelled!

For that reason in this situation, your whole thread awaits for a value that never arrived.

In order to avoid such pitfalls you could use something less "low level" like `racePair` or similar which would avoid dealing with such issues yourself. You can read a short post by Oleg Pyzhcov about [fiber safety](https://olegpy.com/fiber-safety/).